# Vue.js using chart.js options not working

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Hey guys I am currently using example code for vue-chartjs but when I'm trying to add options it does not allow me to add it for some reason. Maybe I am misplacing it, but I'm not sure.

Here is my source code.

```
// CommitChart.js
import {  Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

function getNum(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);}

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted () {
    // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['Yeah', 'What', 'Turnup'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Skimp me',
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          ],
          data: [getNum(), getNum(), getNum()],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ],
      // ATTEMPTING TO ADD OPTIONS. 
      options: {
         scales: {
           yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero:true
           }
          }]
        }
      }
   })
 }
}
```

Everything works but I cannot figure out why this is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can overwrite the default chart options. Just pass the options object as a second parameter to the render method.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs)

Right now your options are within the first object passed in.